# Unable to assign WIT alerts to specific users without who don't have admin rights

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-alerts

A team member without admin rights needs to be notified when WITs are assigned or changed. The login emails for our system is not the same as the work email and assigned to me is the only default option.

Changing the delivery settings and using a custom email doesn't trickle down to the WIT alerts, but works for the rest.

The assigned to field shows @@MyDisplayName@@ OR [Member] and not sure how to make that reflect the users it needs to go to.

Emails being sent to the wrong addresses.

Comment: Hi,BossHogg Is your problem solved? If you have any questions, please feel free to contact me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the **Custom email address** option in the Deliver to drop-down list, then add the mailbox you want to receive the notification  in Address field, so that even if the mailbox is not in your organization, the added mailbox will also receive the notification.

[image]

Comment: That was part of the steps listed as tried. How do you account for the assigned to fields? How will that custom email address know to associate it with that specific person, or will they just get notified when anything is assigned to anyone? The assigned to field shows @@MyDisplayName@@ OR [Member]

Comment: Once the event we set in the Filter criteria is triggered, then the user of the mailbox we specified in the custom email address will receive a notification triggered by this event. In the example I gave, I chose "Changes" for the Operator of the "assigned to" field, so that the "assigned to" field has changed, no matter who it is assigned to, the custom email address will be notified.You can also choose another Operator, like "=", in which the value in the "Value" field shows [Member], the Member here can be modified, you can manually fill in the specified user's mailbox.

Comment: The people that need the alerts don't have admin access, so I'm creating those particular alerts for them. So, if the custom address is used, then will they just get notified when anything is assigned to anyone? There's no way to do it for that specific person with the custom email address?

Comment: Yes ,whether the user of the custom address has permission or not will not affect he receive the notification triggered by the event.